# What's the URL protocol for the iOS Threads app?

Tags: ios

What is the URL protocol to open the Threads app on iOS devices (like `instagram://app` for Instagram)?

Comment: If you can get a hold of the app's IPA file, you can check its `info.plist` to find your answer

Comment: some info here. maybe that can help guide you. barcelona://create?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77693215/220997

Answer (score 0):

The **URL protocol for the iOS Threads app** is `barcelona://user?username={Username}`. You can use this protocol to open the Threads app on iOS devices.

**Example :-** barcelona://user?username={vijai_bishnoi}